# "partially cloudy" or "partly cloudy"?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, adverbs

Do you usually say "the sky is partially cloudy" or "the sky is partly cloudy"? Are they both correct? Is there any difference between "partly and partially" in the last sentence? Is there any difference between "partly" and "partially" in general? They both sound natural to me.

Comment: Go for minimalism! [*The sky is **part-cloudy**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sky+is+part+cloudy%22) Seriously, ***partly*** is fine, but ***partially*** is a bit ott in this context.

Comment: To my ear/mind "partially cloudy" would refer more readily to a haze or filtered sunshine, a different sort of cloud pattern than big bright white cumulous clouds dotting a bright blue sky for partly cloudy...although I think partly cloudy is used commonly for both sorts of days.

Comment: See this Google ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partially+cloudy%2Cpartly+cloudy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartially%20cloudy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpartly%20cloudy%3B%2Cc0 "partly" is far more common.

Comment: Weather forecasters only use "partly" cloudy, they never say "partially cloudy.  However, they are rarely right about the weather, so that casts doubt on everything they say.  On that basis, alone, I'm starting to wonder about "partially".

Comment: "Partly cloudy" is idiomatic in the US for describing weather.

Answer (score 2):

**partly**

in some degree

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/partly?s=t

**partially**

pertaining to a part

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/partially?s=t

The bottom line is **partly cloudy** is an idiomatic phrase. Whatever its drawbacks, it's been in use for quite a while and does roll off the tongue quite naturally.

Comment: Interestingly, the normal way (in U.S. TV meteorologist patois) of describing a shift in weather from "overcast" (that is, completely cloudy) to "partly cloudy" is by using the term "partial clearing."

Answer (score 0):

*Partly cloudy* means that the sky has some cloudy parts and some not cloudy parts.

*Partially clouded over* means that after starting out clear, there was a transition and the blue sky has been gradually, but not completely, obscured by developing (or entering) clouds.